# How to test chat in Quickblox chat application for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, chat, quickblox

I have to make a chat application. I downloaded the chat module sample project from quickblox.com.
I want to test run the chat module on my system which I have downloaded from quickblox.com. I want to create two users and see them chat. 
To do this I created two users by registering them but when I login to the app using the credentials of one of the users, I cannot see the other user which I had created. How can I run two instances of the chat module on two systems and see them chat?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: you sure both users are registered correctly ?

Comment: Yes. While logging in it doesn't allow me unless I enter the correct password. Which means both users have been registered properly.

Comment: where you would like to see them?
Please send a screenshot of this screen

Answer (score 0):

According to my suggestion use 1 Registered account to test in quick-box default demo and use another account in some 3rd party chat application from where you can send message to quick-box and  Receive message .

Here is the best **utility** to test such type of chatting application.

[**adium**](https://adium.im/)

**Use :**

1) Login with quickbox registered account to adium.

2) Login to quickbox sample chat application.

3) Now, Send and Receive message From one to another and test your application.

Note:- You can use adium for any of chat application. Like, **Quickbox , XMPP** demo etc.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox has beautiful chat applications and you can download them by the link 
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk

There is also swift chat sample if you are interested. Thanks!